# Python How to find the coordinate of each point around an oval

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root,width=200,height=200,bg="black")
canvas.pack()
oval = canvas.create_oval(50,50,150,150,fill="white")
print(canvas.bbox(oval))
root.mainloop()
```

I tried this but it gives me the coordinates I gave to create #(49,49,151,151)

is there a code for find the coordinate of each point around an oval.

for example:
[image: oval]
I want to find the coordinate of where the arrow shows

Comment: Surely that's a circle? What were you expecting as the answer?

Comment: `x = r*cos(t)+cx` and `y = r*sin(t)+cy` where `(cx, cy)` is the center of the circle, `t` is the angle in radian and `r` is the radius.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `coords()` function

```
canvas.coors(oval)
```

It should return the tuple with the `(x1, y1, x2, y2)` coordinates

Comment: this gives the coordinates I gave but ı need each point coordinates of border

Comment: @omsel I do not really understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: I added a picture, you can look from there

Answer (score 0):

> is there a code for find the coordinate of each point around an oval.

No, there is not. There is no way to get those coordinates.